# What's the best way to do more complex validation in firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

tldr: Since firebase RTDB security rules only support single-statement conditions and the allowed variables are very limited, I can't check whether a user submission is allowed. What should I do?

I'm making a simple game where users can make weather forecasts ("guesses"). Currently, guesses can be made for tomorrow and the day after tomorrow (I may add the ability to make short-term forecasts for the next few hours as well). Below is what guesses look like in my database. The guess shown, for example, means that a forecast has been made for tornadoes at (30,-20) on Jan 26, 2021, one day in advance ('d1'). The long string is the user ID.

[image: screenshot of part of database]

I want to prevent users from sending guesses for the current day, or a day that has already happened (same would apply for hours if I add that feature). Validation has already been implemented client-side but obviously I need to check on the server.
However, I am not able to do this with RTDB security rules because the only time variable is `now`, the number of milliseconds since the Epoch. The options I can think of are:

1. Restructuring the database somehow so I can use the `now` variable to compare. This might be complicated/impossible.
2. Calling a Firebase Cloud Function for each guess that can validate it. I worry that this may result in a lot of total function invocations.

Is there a 'right' way to solve my problem? Are there options I haven't thought of? Any advice in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining the start of today in milliseconds since the epoch should be possible with:

```
Math.floor(now / (24*60*60*1000)) * (24*60*60*1000)
```

I'm actually not sure of `Math` is available in security rules. If not, you might be able to get somewhere similar with a type-cast or a regular expression.

If you'd like to make this reusable in your Realtime Database, consider using Firebase's [Bolt preprocessor](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt), which has support for [functions](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt).

Comment: Math is not available. Here are all the available features: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database
I will see if accomplishing this with rules is possible.

Comment: So do you recommend not calling a firebase Cloud Function? It it preferred to validate only with security rules?

Comment: Not at all. Using Cloud Functions as an intermediary is a totally valid approach. I just prefer solutions that don't require Cloud Functions, as they are typically easier to keep working when the user is offline.

Comment: Yes. For anyone who may have a similar problem: I changed the way that guesses are added to the database. I replaced the YYMMDD format in the path (ex. '210126') with the latest possible `now` value at which a guess could be submitted for that time frame. This made it really easy to just compare that value to the `now` variable provided by RTDB security rules.